# Keycloak returning multiple access-control-allow-credentials

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I'm trying to create a basic setup using standard flow with the official Keycloak Javascript adapter

Keycloak server is v18
Keycloak-js I have tried with both 18 and 19 versions

The client is configured as follows, basic setup

[image]

When trying to authenticate from Javascript, I receive this error

[image]

And effectively Keycloak is returning 2 acces-control-allow-credentials headers
[image]

I started using keycloak-angular but I have ended up using keycloak-js directly.
The error is always the same

```
const keycloakOptions: KeycloakOptions = {
      config: {
        clientId: config.clientId,
        realm: config.realm,
        url: keycloakUrl,
      },
      initOptions: {

        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        flow: 'standard',
        enableLogging: true,

      },
      enableBearerInterceptor: false,
      loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
    };
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Tried different clients, different keycloak-js libraries, the error is always the same.
Using implicit flow works

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem, it was an extra header added by the proxy serving Keycloak